# Trouble converting dynamic urls into static

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I'm having trouble converting my website's dynamic URL's into static URL's. My hosting plan is shared via bluehost and I have followed their documentation but to no success. Link attached:

https://www.bluehost.com/help/article/htaccess-tutorial

I've been entering the below into .htaccess but nothing happens whenever I access the relevant pages. The code is as follows:

`Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`
`RewriteEngine on`
`RewriteBase /`
`RewriteRule -Victorian-Gondoliers-Boat-Hook-(.*)-product-details_id-(.*)\.html$ product-details?Victorian-Gondoliers-Boat-Hook=$1&product-details_id=$2`

---

https://raven-antiques.com/product-details?Victorian-Gondoliers-Boat-Hook&product-details_id=1000001087

To be more exact, I would like to convert the above url into:

https://raven-antiques.com/product-details/Victorian-Gondoliers-Boat-Hook

My product details page is a page-product-details.php dynamic file which relies on GET statements to echo out the unique product details.

Is this a user permission problem given that the hosting plan is shared or have I entered something in incorrectly?

Yours Sincerely, Gregory.

Comment: Could you please do mention with sample URLs from which URL to which URL you want to rewrite or redirect? Please post detailed information in your question to make it clear, thank you.

Comment: Hi Ravinder, thank you for your correct. Just edited the above.

Comment: Thanks for editing, do you have file named `product-details` present in your system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your shown samples and attempts, please try following Rules file. Please do clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([\w-]+)\?([^&]*)&details_id=\d+\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2?  [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?$2&$1_id=1000001087 [QSA,NC,L]
```